# Computing the Expected value of the random variable "Filled urns"

Tags: probability, expectation

I was thinking in the following problem:

Imagine you have $N$ urns and $b$ balls, so you define the random variable $X= \text{number of filled urns}$, then a question arises, How can one know which is the Expected value $E[X]$ of $X$?

I thought this was a new one but someone told me that this was a well known result and in fact that

$$E[X]=N(1-e^{-b/N})$$

So how this could be? I can't figure out why is this true.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ urn.  That is, $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ urn is empty, $0$ otherwise.

By Linearity of Expectation we know that the answer $E$ is given by: $$E=E\left[\sum X_i\right]=\sum E[X_i]=Np$$  Where $p$ is the probability that any specified urn is empty. It's easy to compute that $p=\left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^b$ So $$E=N\times \left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^b$$

If $N$ is very large, the standard limit definition of the exponential shows that your formula is a decent approximation.

Comment: How did you got $p$ ?

Comment: @user162343 $p$ is the probability that no balls are in urn# $i$, ie that all $b$ are in the $N-1$ other urns.

Comment: The probability that one ball misses the specified urn is $\frac {N-1}N$.  The probability that $2$ do is $\left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^2$, and so on.

Comment: Ok so you just use the normal computation of probabilities, I mean if $S$ is your sample space and $E$ is your event then the probability $P$ is $P=|S|/|E|$ right?

Comment: Other way round.

Comment: @lulu which standard definition of the exponential are you using?

Comment: @user162343 The [standard limit definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Overview): $e^x := \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\tfrac xn\right)^n$

Comment: Right @GrahamKemp but how does the above is the limit you are taking when $N$ is large?

Comment: So...for large $N$, $E=N\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac 1N\right)^b$.  Now just use the fact that $\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac 1N\right)^N=e^{-1}$

Comment: @lulu Thanks but Can you help me with this one please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934556/how-to-check-this-formula-of-expectation