# The urn problem but with a modification (How does that change the solution?)

Tags: probability, expectation

[These problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928512/computing-the-expected-value-of-the-random-variable-filled-urns) is solved in one hand, but then one can ask the following:

> **Question**

Imagine that you have $N$ urns and $b$ balls, you throw the balls and each of them gets into a urn with a probability $p$ or bounce and gets outside the urn with probability $1-p$ so then if we define $$X=\textit{number of filled urns}\;$$ which will be now $E[X]$?

I suspect, by analogy that

$$E[X]=N(1-e^{bp/N})$$

The thing is that I don't know how if my guess is right and how to figure out it.

> **Attempts:**

**1)** I was trying the following, one defines the random variable,

$$X_{(n)}=\text{number of occupied urns when we throw $n$ balls}$$

then we get that

$$X_{(1)}=1$$

so $X_{(2)}$ could be either $1$ or $2$, so in general one gets that

$$X_{(n)}= X_{(n-1)}+1 \; \text{with probability } \; \frac{X_{(n-1)}}{N}$$

or

$$X_{(n)}= X_{(n-1)} \; \text{with probability } \; \frac{N-X_{(n-1)}}{N}$$

Then we get the recurrence formula:

$$E[X_{(n)}]= (X_{(n-1)}+1)(\frac{X_{(n-1)}}{N})+ (X_{(n-1)})(\frac{N-X_{(n-1)}}{N})$$

But I don't know how to proceed from this.

**2)** Another thing that can be done is using the above idea but with the conditional expectation, the thing is that I don't know if is a good way of doing it, since we don't know anything about the distribution functions of the random variables $X_{(n)}$.

**3)** Doing an analogy to what was post in my previous question one only has to modify the probability of being in any urn to the probability of being thrown in any urn, this is

$$(\frac{N-1}{N})^{b} \to (\frac{N-1}{N})^{bp}$$

Am I right?.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The easiest way is to compute the probability that one specific urn is occupied.  The chance that one ball goes in is ???.  The chance that one ball doesn't go in is ???.  The chance that none of the balls goes in is ???.  The chance the urn is occupied is ???.  This is the expectation of the variable that is $1$ when the urn is occupied and $0$ otherwise.  Now by the linearity of expectation, the expected number of occupied urns is ???  The fact that some balls miss just reduces the effective number of balls to $pb$

Comment: So my 3rd attempt is the correct one right?

Comment: Why the effective number of balls reduces to $pb$ Can you explain that please?

Comment: Because that is the number of balls that actually go into urns.  Yes, your approach 3 works fine.

Comment: So as I said my third attempt is right, isn't ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more in the $pb$ part please? Thanks

Comment: Basically you can take each ball and first decide whether it hits some urn or not.  $pb$ of the balls (on average) will hit urns, so you are in the same state were you had $pb$ balls and guaranteed that each one hits an urn.  Then you decide which urn it hits and go on.  The linearity of expectation relieves you about worrying about correlations, such as if one urn turns up empty it is more likely that a specific other one will be full.

Comment: Why on average? this is what do you mean by average?

Comment: Each one hits an urn independently with probability $p$, but you might be lucky and get more than $pb$ hitting urns or unlucky and have less.  It is like flipping a coin.  On average you get $1/2$ heads, but it might be somewhat more or less.

Comment: What can you say about my first approach?

Comment: How can one do it with that approach?

Comment: The first approach is correct, but as you see it bogs down in the probability distribution of how many urns are occupied at each step along the way.  I don't know how to get to an answer in the general case that way.  In a sense the expected number of occupied urns is deceptively simple.  Because of the linearity of expectation it comes out easily.  If I ask you for the chance that three urns are unoccupied as a function of $pb$ it is much harder.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part please ? Thanks

Comment: Why is that last part much harder? Thanks